# Uniqueness Validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique

I am trying to apply validation of uniqueness to the field name custom_link. But it is allowing to add same values in the field.
Following is my model:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
....
validates :custom_link, uniqueness: true
....
end
```

This is my code of controller:

```
def update
      respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to galleries_galleryhome_path(id: params[:id]), notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   end
private:

def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :shoot_date, :release_date, :expiration_date, :archive,:gallery_layout_id, :contact_id,:status, :cover_url,:gallery_photo_id, photos_attributes: [:image]).merge(brand_id: current_brand.id,user_id: current_user.id)
    end
```

Getting no idea why it is not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you read the docs about what `uniqueness` can and can't do?

Comment: Hi, Can you please share your controller code, Because you have written the write syntax it should work.

Comment: @Bharat Soni, I have shared the code of my controller

Comment: Why you didn't permit the custom_link attribute in strong parameters, Please do that and then test again.

Comment: @Bharatsoni is right, the `custom_link` field should be whitelisted there. Also, why are you using `update`? Should be `@gallery.save(gallery_params)`

Comment: @Bharat soni that was a silly mistake of mine. i have added custom_link to strong parameters, but still its not working.

Comment: @sequielo i am using update beacuse i am updating the records. Initially when gallery is created it does not stores any value in custom_link.

Answer (score 0):

Try considering case.

```
validates :custom_link, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
```

Can you provide an example of what is allowed to be created more than once?

When are you creating the same value, on new creation, on update of an existing object, etc?

Comment: Thanx for the reply Keith. I have tried this too. But it is not working. And i am trying to create the same value at the time of update.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a unique index in your DB, as stated in: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

> 2.11 uniqueness
>   This helper validates that the attribute's value is unique right before the object gets saved. It does not create a
>   uniqueness constraint in the database, so it may happen that two
>   different database connections create two records with the same value
>   for a column that you intend to be unique. To avoid that, you must
>   create a unique index on both columns in your database. See the MySQL
>   manual for more details about multiple column indexes.

Add a migration with that constraint as follow:

```
rails g migration add_uniqueness_to_custom_link
```

Then write the new index:

```
self.change
   add_index :galleries, :custom_link, unique: true
end
```

And finally: `rake db:migrate`